# Arrange list of ggplot plots and adjust spacing/margin

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have a function that creates a list of ggplot plots. I'm currently using patchwork to arrange the plots together in a way that I can knit to Word, but I'm having a hard time with the way it looks when it renders. The output currently looks like this:

[image: bad figure]

I'd like to make it so that it looks like this:

[image: good figure]

Currently, my code is the following:

```
patchwork_plots <- Reduce(`+`, plots)

patchwork_plots + 
  plot_layout(ncol=2)
```

I've tried a few different packages and different ways of adjusting, but nothing really seems to work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Try `purrr::reduce(plots,`+`)`

Comment: The relevant code here would likely be whatever you are using to knit to word. The difference between your two plots is the output size, there is nothing wrong with the patchwork code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to just change your aspect ratio and `width=` and `height=` of the plot.  The graphics in your plots will not scale the same as the text in the plot, but will depend on the resolution and size/aspect ratio of your graphics device.  Here is an example that shows 3 very different-looking plots that can result from adjusting the aspect ratio of your output.

```
library(ggplot2)
# intentionally crowded plot
gplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(factor(cyl)~factor(carb), scales='free') +
  labs(x='mpg is here and this is long', y='disp is here and this is long too!')
```

### Width = 4, Height = 3

```
ggsave('plot4_3.png', width=4, height=3)
```

[image]

### Width = 8, Height = 5

```
ggsave('plot8_5.png', width=8, height=5)
```

[image]

### Width = 12, Height =  9

```
ggsave('plot12_9.png', width=12, height=9)
```

[image]